# How can I compute the adjoint representation of ${\rm SU}(2)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am trying to figure out how the famous three matrices are obtained:

\begin{equation}
T_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&-i\\0&i&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&i\\0&0&0\\-i&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-i&0\\i&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

But I don't have any idea of how to get there from the generators of ${\rm SU}(2)$. I've tried to use the usual definition of the adjoint representation, but can't get any result.

Comment: What did you obtain? It might be that you got the correct result but in a different basis.

Comment: $(t^k)_{ij}=f_{ij}{}^k$?